# Reposition android virtual keyboard to right of screen in landscape mode

Tags: android

I have am developing an android app for V2.2 onwards.

The app is for numeric data input for the elderly

To keep things nice and simple, I am using the phone style input method.  This also has the advantage of using nice big keys for them.

In landscape mode, I would like to move the virtual keyboard and position it on the right hand side of the view.  The content itself has much more height than width and it would be perfect to have the screen split down the middle horizontally with the content on the left and the virtual keyboard on the right.

Does anyone know if this is possible?

Thanks

Comment: I believe to do this you would need to create a custom IME, I don't think you can do it from within your app..

Comment: I just stumbled on android.inputmethodservice.KeyboardView, has anyone used that before?  Also, does anyone know if you can force the numeric phone style keyboard to always display a decimal point?  It does this on the google nexus one but not on other devices (including the emulator).  Thanks.